Simulation methods for load current? (LT SPICE)
First of all, thanks for click this post.
I study about inrush currents. Anyway I do wanna simulate as possible as real cases.
This circuit is about load switch and in real case the load consumes about 200mA but my simulation gets 0.1 mA levels.
Thanks

Fig.1 The real circuit

Fig.2 Measurement results

Fig.3 LTSPICE schematics

Fig.4 LTSPICE results (Y-Axis is mA)
